# How to open several gazebos in a linux operating system?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I can use the `gazebo` command to start Gazebo in my Linux. However, when I open a new terminal and type in `gazebo` (for the second time), then nothing happens. How can I run several Gazebo instances at the same time in my Linux?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15897/how-to-open-several-gazebos-in-a-linux-operating-system?/) by [shin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3184/shin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3184/shin/) on 2017-04-17**:
I have create several `gzserver` with different `localhosts`, then I create corresponding `gzclient`. It is strange that all clients do same operation as if they had received same instructions, but I connect them to `gzserver` with different `localhosts`. What determines the server? How can I use different server to control different client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

To run various Gazebo instances, you must make sure each of them is using a different port. You can set this with the `GAZEBO_MASTER_URI` environment variable.

It's also convenient to run Gazebo in verbose mode so you can read error messages.

For example, on one terminal, start `gzserver` on the default port (11345):

`gzserver --verbose`

You'll see the port printed in green:

`[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345`

Then on a new terminal, open `gzclient`:

`gzclient --verbose`

You'll see the same port printed in green:

`[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345`

If you try to start another `gzserver` on a new terminal, without changing the URI, you'll get an error:

`[Err] [Master.cc:96] EXCEPTION: Unable to start server[bind: Address already in use]. There is probably another Gazebo process running.`

The correct way is to open a new terminal and start another instance with a new URI:

`export GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11346; gzserver --verbose`

This time the URI is different:

`[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11346`

And then on a new terminal, the respective `gzclient`:

`export GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11346; gzclient --verbose`

And you should also see the same URI:

`[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11346`

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3184/shin/) on 2017-04-17**:
By your instructions, I can really open multiple gazebo, however, when I use some control instructions, the models of all windows move in the same way. Can I just control only one window at one time and keep the states of other windows unchanged?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-04-17**:
How are you sending instructions? You should be able to specify the URI to send them to and only that simulation will be affected. For example, if you use the gz command line tool, you should specify GAZEBO_MASTER_URI for the shell where you're running it.

**Comment by [shin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3184/shin/) on 2017-04-17**:
I am playing a project, I guess the instructions have been packed. Can I specify URI when I open gzserver? If I do so, it will tell me no correct URl, and use old value, how can I solve it ?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-04-17**:
I added more detailed instructions. Note that the URI must be set for each gzclient/gzserver you start.

**Comment by [shin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3184/shin/) on 2017-04-18**:
This approach does work in some projects, but interesting things happen in project `haptix`, if I open two gazebo in this way, when I use keyboard to control the arms, two arms in different clients will act in same way. However, if I use the C API of this project to control, I can only control the one who was opened earier, even if I use the hx_connection to set host and port, it seems useless, I guess this may be related to the principle of gzserver, could you give me some ideas?

**Comment by [amit1989](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6941/amit1989/) on 2018-10-17**:
@chapulina as described above, I am able to run multiple gazebo instant and get data from it by putting export GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11345
I am using C++ standalone plugin.
So how to do it programmatically? What should I add in my program to do this automatically?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-10-17**:
@amit1989, this sounds good for a new question

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

@chapulina already described the instructions for running multiple instances of Gazebo. Here are some additional notes that can help when working with the HAPTIX environment:

You should be able to isolate a Gazebo instance and your HAPTIX controllers with the help of the `IGN_PARTITION` environment variable. If you set this environment variable in the terminal where you launch Gazebo and in the terminal that you use to control the arm, other Gazebo instances shouldn't be affected by your controller. E.g.:

On terminal 1:

```
IGN_PARTITION=arm1 gazebo <your_world>
```

On terminal 2:

```
IGN_PARTITION=arm1 ./<my_controller>
```

Replace `<your_world>` with the appropriate Gazebo .world file and `<my_controller>` with the program that you're using for controlling the simulated arm.

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2017-04-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3184/shin/) on 2017-04-19**:
This approach works perfectly! Thank you very much!

**Comment by [shin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3184/shin/) on 2017-04-26**:
By your instructions, I can control different robot arm as I want. However, I can only control one arm in each time point because the environment variable IGN_PARTITION is unique in each time point. If I want to control two or more arms in the same time, how to do that? I try to use the function hx_connection, but I can not find its implementation, so it is difficult for me to use it. Could you please give me some more ideas? Thank you very much!